# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a VUE PWA and getting this error.
It doesn't give off the error in localhost so i'm guessing its a build problem.
My service worker is in the same directory as my index.html so i don't think that it is a problem where it can't find and fetch the file. I've been going over this for days and can't seem to find any solution.
If anyone has one, do let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this by changing the file name that it registers on registerServiceWorker.js
I was using the Vue-Cli3 to help create the boiler template for the PWA and it is default pointing towards the made service worker file -->

```
register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {....
```

so you need to change the name to your specific new service worker file, which in my change is to the firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}firebase-messaging-sw.js`, {....
```